# Is it possible to persist data in GAE/java without using annotations?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm looking to add google-app-engine datastore persistence to one of my projects. So far, I've been reluctant to use the annotations, since I would want to have multiple DAO implementations ( e.g. Hibernate vs. GAE datastore ).

Is there a way to have the persistence configuration done without annotations? I found no hints in the [official guide](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/).

---

Please note that I don't want to use the JPA annotations, no matter how standard, since:

- the JPA implementation is incomplete;
- it still ties my model to a persistence implementation.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to have special objects for persistence, mirroring the model. But that is way to complicated to consider seriously.